# Split a string as 2x16 for LCD

Tags: lcd

How do I split a string into two based on it's length to display on a 2x16 LCD?

I have seen a function called length() to get the length of a string. But, any ideas how to split it in to 2x16 and trim the rest of the string?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String::Substring does take a start and an end value. So you can do something like this:

```
String s1 = longtext.substring(0,15);
String s2 = longtext.substring(16,31);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`String::substring()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringSubstring) is for. Simply take the first 16 characters and the characters from 16 to 32, and output them.

Comment: But,what about the rest of the string? I need 2 x 16 of the 32. Substring only provides one part right?

Comment: Use it as many times as you need in order to get all desired substrings.